# Crash in UpdateRenderTargetView methode DirectX12

Tags: crash, access-violation, directx-12

So I looked into some tutorials for DirectX12 and when I copied the code that I downloaded from [here](https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-1/) it worked but when I brought them into a class and wanted to use it, it just crashes in UpdateRenderTargetView method at the `m_BackBuffers[i] = backBuffer;`

It says:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF831C65FA1 (d3d10warp.dll) in Hazelnut.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location

The Code:

```
void D3D12Core::UpdateRenderTargetViews(ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain4> swapChain, ComPtr<ID3D12DescriptorHeap> descriptorHeap)
{
    auto rtvDescriptorSize = m_Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle(descriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());

    for (int i = 0; i < m_BufferCount; ++i)
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> BackBuffer;
        swapChain->GetBuffer(i, IID_PPV_ARGS(&BackBuffer));

        m_Device->CreateRenderTargetView(BackBuffer.Get(), nullptr, rtvHandle);

        m_BackBuffers[i] = BackBuffer;

        rtvHandle.Offset(rtvDescriptorSize);
    }
}
```

Class members That I used in function:

```
 class D3D12Core
{
 public:
    //Some members
    static const uint8_t m_BufferCount = 3;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> m_BackBuffers[m_BufferCount];
 private:
    ComPtr<ID3D12Device2> m_Device;
    //Some members
};
```

I tried everything that I could but didn't find the cause.
Normally it shouldn't crash at all.
Please be gentle.I'm new to Stackoverflow.
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

[D3D12Core](https://pastebin.com/JcTmq0AT)

[D3D12Core Implementation](https://pastebin.com/T2ww3j1w)

And I use it like this:

```
auto commnadQueue = D3D12Core::Get().GetCommandQueue(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT);
m_SwapChain = D3D12Core::Get().CreateSwapChain(m_WindowHandle, commnadQueue->GetD3D12CommandQueue(), m_Width, m_Height);
m_RTVDescriptorHeap = D3D12Core::Get().CreateDescriptorHeap(1, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
D3D12Core::Get().UpdateRenderTargetViews(m_SwapChain, m_RTVDescriptorHeap);
```

the UpdateRenderTargetViews function will get call by another function in window class that will be used for WndProc.
I didn't write in which class or file this written I don't think it will be necessary.

Comment: Have you enabled debug layer?

Comment: I thought so but I did it in a wrong way. I fixed but when it crashes it says: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8433BA839 (KernelBase.dll) in Hazelnut.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000653693C1C0, 0x000000653693DFB0).

Comment: Can you post your D3D12Core class somewhere, e.g. pastebin, because there is nothing wrong with a code you have posted. Did you ensure that your descriptor heap and swap chain are initialized?

Comment: Here is the links to pastebin:[D3D12Core](https://pastebin.com/JcTmq0AT)      [D3D12Core implementation](https://pastebin.com/T2ww3j1w) and I'm sure that swap chain and descriptor heap are initialized.

Comment: Ok, can you also post snippet where you make the calls to UpdateRenderTargetViews because I don't see those in implementation so I am guessing they are somewhere else?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after you provided some more source code, I am pretty sure the mistake is here:

```
m_RTVDescriptorHeap = D3D12Core::Get().CreateDescriptorHeap(1, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
```

which should actually be

```
m_RTVDescriptorHeap = D3D12Core::Get().CreateDescriptorHeap(D3D12Core::m_BufferCount, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
```

You are offseting the handle in a for loop which goes out of bounds in second iteration.

Comment: Oh, I cannot believe how idiot I was. Because of a simple mistake I was searching a day to fix it ._. . Thx a lot for this zezanjee.